# Why do I get two different conditions on Polar form and rectangular form?

Tags: complex-analysis, solution-verification, complex-numbers, polar-coordinates

The question is to prove "If $z+\frac{1}{z}$ is real either Im(z)=0 or |z|=1"

While solving using rectangular form, I get the imaginary part as $y(x^2+y^2)-y$ which is zero $\implies$ either y=0 or $x^2+y^2=1$.

But while solving using Polar form :
$z + \frac{1}{z} = |z| \cos \theta + i|z| \sin \theta + |z| \cos \theta - i|z| \sin \theta $ which is equal to $2 \cos \theta$.
So the imaginary part being $0$ irrespective of $z$ such that $z \neq 0$.  Am I doing something wrong, if yes where? if no why do I get different answers?

Comment: Polar form reciprocal is not Correct

Comment: Instead of writing $z^{-1}$ in polar form you wrote $\bar z$ (the complex conjugate of $z$). Of course $z + \bar z$ is always real.

Comment: Alt. hint $\;-\;$ using that $w$ is real iff $w = \bar w \iff w - \bar w = 0\,$, and $w \bar w = |w|^2$:

$$
0 = \left(z + \frac{1}{z}\right) - \left(\bar z + \frac{1}{\bar z}\right) = (z - \bar z)\left(1 - \frac{1}{|z|^2}\right) \;\;\implies\;\; \ldots
$$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $Z = r[\cos\theta + i\sin\theta]$

then $1/Z = [\cos\theta - i\sin\theta]/r$

Hence $Z + 1/Z = r[\cos\theta + i\sin\theta] + [\cos\theta - i\sin\theta]/r$

This is $[r^2\cos\theta + ir^2\sin\theta + \cos\theta - i\sin\theta]/r$

This is real when $[ir^2\sin\theta - i\sin\theta] = 0$

That is : Either $\sin \theta = 0$ Or $r^2-1=0$

That is : Either $\theta = 0$ (Positive real number) Or $\theta = \pi$ (Negative real number) $\implies$ [ Zero Imaginary Part ]
Or $r=1$ $\implies$ [ Unit Number with Modulus 1 ]

DONE

You had wrong Polar reciprocal , which gave the wrong Conclusion.

Comment: Thank you so much guys.. I thought I did some silly mistake but unable to find where it is, thanks for pointing it out...